# Execute API call for each row in Dataframe (scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I using scala and spark ,
and trying to execute for each row in Dataframe, post request , and parse the response from API .
One of the columns in the DF is the body for each row . (co1,col2,col3..,body).
Is it right to execute:

```
val responses = df.map(r=> executePost(r))
```

in this case , spark will parallel the calls between the executers automatically?

- executePost - make http post , and parsing response to case-class.

Thanks!

Comment: it depends on how have you handled in `executePost` . If it's a synchronous call (wait for response), then It will perform as expected. But it it's asynchronous , then you will have unexpected results .

Comment: Hi , Yes , executePost is synchronous.                                                                   
 There is something strange , when i'm looking at the logs of each executor, I can see that some of the requests (not all of them) , executed 1 time on each executor (totally 3 times instead of 1).

Comment: can you check for duplicates on `df` ? A single row will be executed only once for sure in case of `map`.

Answer (score 0):

yes spark will parallele the call, each executor will call your API in same time.